# TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Переписал код с sqlite3 >>>

```
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def get_questions(self):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('select id, questions from database', ()).fetchall()
            data = {}
            for row in result:
                questions = tuple(row[1].split(';'))
                data[row[0]] = questions
            return data

    def get_answer(self, answer_id):
        with self.connection:
            if answer_id == 47:
                return self.cursor.execute('SELECT answer FROM bad_words_answer ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1').fetchone()[0]
            else:
                return self.cursor.execute('select answer from database where id = ?', (answer_id,)).fetchone()[0]
```

На sqlalchemy >>>

```
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{db_file}', echo=False)

    def get_questions(self):
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            query = text('SELECT id, questions FROM database')
            result = conn.execute(query)

            data = {}
            for row in result:
                questions = tuple(row[1].split(';'))
                data[row[0]] = questions

            return data

    def get_answer(self, answer_id):
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            if answer_id == 47:
                query = text('SELECT answer FROM bad_words_answer ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
                result = conn.execute(query)
                return result.fetchone()[0]
            else:
                query = text('SELECT answer FROM database WHERE id = :id')
                result = conn.execute(query, id=answer_id)
                return result.fetchone()[0]
```

В коде на sqlalchemy при плохом слове бот отвечает т.е. работает.
Если задаешь вопрос (бот должен найти его в бд и вывести соответствующий ответ, все ответы имеют id) то выдает ошибку - `result = conn.execute(query, id=answer_id) TypeError: Connection.execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

Прошу помочь

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка тут, потому что передаете параметр id в метод conn.execute() как именованный параметр, а в sqlalchemy параметры передаются в виде словаря.

```
def get_answer(self, answer_id):
    with self.engine.connect() as conn:
        if answer_id == 47:
            query = text('SELECT answer FROM bad_words_answer ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
            result = conn.execute(query)
            return result.fetchone()[0]
        else:
            query = text('SELECT answer FROM database WHERE id = :id')
            result = conn.execute(query, {'id': answer_id})
            return result.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: спасибо! всё работает